# Using android layout inflater

Tags: android

I want to use layout inflater

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.durum_yazi);
    sayac=0;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

But eclipse is giving this error for layoutinfalter line:

activity cannot be resolved.

Ps:I am using support library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

use

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```